# How to use environment variables with docker-compose from other directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm setting up a new docker-based server and I'm writing a script to run

```
$ docker-compose
```

for all my `docker-compose.yml` files at once.

I know about existence of `.env` files and I know about `env_file` option in `docker-compose.yml`, however the `.env` files are ignored when I launch

```
$ docker-compose up
```

from other directory and not even full path in `env_file` helps.

**my_script.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose up -f /server1/docker-compose.yml -f /server2/docker-compose.yml -f /server3/docker-compose.yml
```

**Docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  service_name:
    build: /server1/apache
    env_file: /server1/.env
    volumes:
      - /web/${ROOT_DOMAIN}/web/:/var/www/:rw
```

.env

```
ROOT_DOMAIN=server1.domain.tld
```

I want to replace the `${ROOT_DOMAIN}` variable in volumes for the variable defined in `.env` file. This works like a charm, when I run

```
$ docker-compose up
```

from the `/server1/` folder. However when I run my script, which is in other directory, the enviroment variables are ignored and default to null.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry to say, but this cannot be fixed. The provided `.env` file must be in the same directory.

This is a requirement of docker compose and is described in the docs (first paragraph): https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

Comment: How about a symlink?

Comment: it is possible setting the flag --env-file for example: docker-compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev up.  Further details here https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: My file is in the same directory and the docker file still knows nothing about the variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the flag --env-file to set the path where the .env file is located, example:

docker-compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev up

Official Docker documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: this worked for me, tried using the env_file option in my docker-compose yaml but that wasnt working.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own:

```
function execute() {    
    (set -a;  source .env;  cat $1 | envsubst | kubectl apply -f -)
}

execute foo.yaml
```

And

```
$ cat .env
FOO=123
BAR=abc

$ cat foo.yaml
{
    "myfoo": $FOO,
    "mybar": $BAR
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using flag didn't work for me, but since I'm using node I created a script which copies the .env file across before running it.

If you aren't using node you could run a bash script which essentially does the same thing.

```
"scripts":
{
   "build_postgres":"cp .env node-app/pg/.env && cd node-app/pg && docker-compose up", 
}
```

**Warning**

Just be sure to exclude the .env file from your .gitignore in case of sensitive information ending up in git repo.

.gitignore

```
node-app/pg/.env
```

**note:**

Be sure your .env file variables are uppercase and values

```
PG_USER=myuser
```